# ng-grid Pass arabic header

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I have `ng-grid` and want bind it with this Object in Javascript:

```
 $scope.myData = [{ يوم: "Moroni", age: 50 },
              { يوم: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
              ];

$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
```

the html is:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

when i see the grid it look like

[image]

and no value come in column 'يوم', but if the column is in english its return result.

Any solution for the problem please

Comment: I would be interested to know why someone down voted this...

Comment: If i know i will tell you , but no answer

Comment: does it still fail if you wrap your arabic headers with quotes/double quotes like so: [{ "يوم": "Moroni", age: 50 },{ "يوم": "Tiancum", age: 43 }] ?

Comment: ya it still the same you can try it from here

http://plnkr.co/edit/T6qaQX?p=preview

the problem from Aabic Name not from the quotation

Comment: @AHMAD I posted a solution to your question: please check provided plunker and tell me if it fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind keeping latin alphabet for variable names, there is a workaround.

You need to add the following to `$scope.gridOptions`:

```
columnDefs: [
        {field:"name",displayName:"يوم"},
        { field: 'age', displayName: 'age' }
      ]
```

---

Please find [workaround plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nNKK4n?p=preview)